# I have a list of strings paired with a number. I want to find the average value for each word that matches to a list of words. How can I do this?

Tags: python

Below is an example of what I am referring to.  'injury' is located both in the second and third string with a value of 100,000 and 50,000 respectively.  So the average value for injury would be 75,000.  But 'slip' is only located in the first string, so it would have an average value of 150,000.  I would like to apply this logic to analyze a database.  Are there any suggestions on how to approach this using python?

```
word_list = ['loss', 'fault', 'slip', 'fall', 'injury']

data_list = [('there was a slip and fall', 150000), ('injury and loss', 100000), ('injury at fault', 50000)]

Output = [('injury', 75000), ('loss', 100000), ('slip', 150000), ('fall', 150000), ('fault', 50000)]
```

Comment: Although I wish there were, there is no stackexchange site that is dedicated to writing code.  We will try to help if you have a problem with your code, but we won't write it for you.

Comment: @Cole did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stripping the syntax errors from your example, here's one solution using loops. I don't think there's any neat comprehension you can pull off here, but I'm eager to be proven wrong. I used floats for accuracy, convert to int as needed. I also assumed the order of your `Output` does not matter, since I cannot make out any intrinsic order that would make sense. That being said, this should get you started:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
word_list = ['loss', 'fault', 'slip', 'fall', 'injury']
data_list = [('there was a slip and fall', 150000), ('injury and loss', 100000), ('injury at fault', 50000)] 
split_list = [(set(x.split()), y) for x,y in data_list]

for word in word_list:
    for stringset, count in split_list:
        if word in stringset:
            d[word]['seen'] = d[word].get('seen', 0) + 1
            d[word]['count'] = d[word].get('count', 0) + count

print([(word, float(d[word]['count'])/d[word]['seen']) for word in d])
```

Output:

```
[('loss', 100000.0), ('injury', 75000.0), ('fall', 150000.0), ('slip', 150000.0), ('fault', 50000.0)]
```